# Variation of Jensen's formula and the argument principle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I came across this problem in my Complex Analysis class:

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ be a meromorphic function on U. Let $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a compact supported smooth function. Then show that
$$\sum_\rho g(\rho) - \sum_\zeta g(\zeta) = \frac{-1}{2\pi}\int\int_U ((\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})g(x+iy))\frac{f'}{f}(x+iy)dxdy = $$ $$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\int_U ((\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y})g(x+iy))\log(|f(x+iy)|) dxdy$$
Where $\rho$ and $\zeta$ are zeros and singularities of $f$ on the support of g.
My attempt on this problem is trying to use the argument principle. I first tried working locally on a small disc in the support of $g$, whose boundary avoids the zeros and singularities of $f$. Then applying Green's theorem on the integral $$\int\int_D (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})(g(x+iy) \frac{f'}{f}(x+iy))dxdy,$$ which should give me something like $$\int_{\partial D}g(z)\frac{f'}{f}(z) dz.$$ I am somewhat confident that this will work given the constraint that $g$ is holomorphic, using the residue theorem. However the argument doesn't seem to work if $g$ is instead smooth, which seems unavoidable. I am also not so sure about how to establish the second equality. It looks like using some variant of integration by parts, but I don't see it concretely. I've consulted the lecturer today and was told to apply Green's or Stoke's theorem. Any more hints or ideas on this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: But is this smooth in the sense of real analysis i.e. $U\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ or is this smooth in the sense of complex analysis i.e. (infinitely) differentiable, holomorphic, analytic

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this is smooth in the sense of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which means having partial derivatives of all orders.